# How can I type hint a function parameter as requiring a concrete class inheriting from a certain type in Python?

Tags: python, abstract-class, python-typing

In this example, I have an abstract class `Thing`, where child classes can be registered using `registerAThing()`. I want to annotate this `registerAThing()` function so that only concrete subclasses of `Thing` are allowed by a type checker, as a way to ensure that only classes where the `foo()` function is implemented are considered to match the type requirements. How can I do this?

```py
# My abstract base class
class Thing:
    @abstractmethod
    def foo():
        ...

# A function for registering concrete Things
# No abstract Things allowed
# How can I annotate this?
def registerAThing(thing: type[Thing]):
    ...

# A concrete Thing
class Thing1(Thing):
    def foo():
        pass

# Another abstract Thing
class Thing2(Thing):
    def bar():
        pass

# Should pass type checks
registerAThing(Thing1)

# Should fail type checks as foo() isn't implemented
registerAThing(Thing2)
```

Comment: I don’t know if this is possible, but even if it is, what’s the point? At runtime, you can pass any garbage to `registerAThing`.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I understand that at runtime it can't provide safety, much like all type hinting in Python. However, type annotations still provide huge amounts of program safety as they make it much quicker to recognise bugs. In this case, registering a `Thing` where not all the methods are implemented could cause many difficult-to-find bugs. Having an error flagged by my type checker would make it much easier to recognise those cases, which would save massive amounts of time.

Comment: I don’t know of any compiled language that can type check if a method has been implemented merely by generics, and Python isn’t even a compiled language. Generics is meant for types, not for methods. You’re welcome to try though, perhaps some Python ninja will help you.

Comment: Doesn't  [`Type[Thing]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type) already do what you want?!

Comment: @deceze sadly no, since it just expects a `Thing`, not necessarily a concrete `Thing` like `Thing1`

Comment: Fine, so you *could* pass `Thing` itself, but you *couldn't instantiate it* (if you made it a proper `ABC`), so what?

Comment: @deceze This example is heavily simplified. In actuality, I need to register the objects so that they can be instantiated when necessary. In a few years of development, there could be potentially hundreds of them (each one implements the interface for communicating with a different device). I decided that it was far cleaner for each object to register itself rather than have every single one be imported somewhere else one by one, especially since each one will most-likely maintained by a different person.

Comment: Yes, but you’re describing a standard use case for abstract classes: you define the abstract class as proper `ABC` with `abstractmethod`s, and type hint that abstract class everywhere needed. The abstract base class is not instantiable, and it’s understood that you want concrete subclasses wherever there’s a type hint for the base class.

Comment: It turns out that this is an issue with Pylance's type checker (even when it's set to strict). Mypy picks up on it fine and gives the expected error with no changes.